# Private browsing mode in UIWebView and sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, safari, sessionstorage

Does a UIWebView under iOS inherit the private browsing mode setting from Safari?

I have had issues with sessionStorage and private mode in mobile safari and I'm trying to assess if I could face similar issues pulling the page into a UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes UIWebView does have the private browsing mode by default. The Cookie data is accessible by the App only.
NSHTTPCookie's singleton instance stores the Cookie information of the UIWebView. You may need to use `deleteCookie:` method to clear the cached data.

Comment: So this setting isn't shared with Safari? And is it actually a private mode, or just for 'all intents and purposes'?

Comment: No these settings aren't shared with Safari. Yes it is private mode and the UIWebView Cookies can be accessed by the object instance only. I hope that clears your doubt.